# Title: Angular: ActivatedRoute returns null for parameter in URL

Tags: angular, url-routing, angular-router, url-parameters

I'm trying to retrieve a parameter value from the URL in my Angular component using the **`ActivatedRoute`** service, but I'm getting a **`null`** value for the parameter. Here's my URL:

**http://localhost:4200/question/edit/2**

Here's my route configuration:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'question/edit/:id',
    component: AddQuestionComponent
  }
];
```

And here's the code I'm using in my **`AddQuestionComponent`**:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
  const id = Number(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
  console.log(id); // Output: null
}
```

I expect the **`console.log()`** statement to output **`2`**, but it's outputting **`null`**. I've also tried accessing the **`params`** property directly (**`this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id`**), but that also returns **`null`**.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try following instead

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {
const id = Number(params['id']);
  console.log(id);
})
```

Comment: the result for your code is NaN

Comment: try to log params to console and see what you are getting there

Comment: Value is empty.
_value: {}

Answer (score 0):

Solution One:

```
const id = Number(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('id'));
console.log(id); // Output: null
```

Solution Two:

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
  const id = Number(params['id']);
  console.log(id);
})
```

Solution Three:

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {
  const id = Number(params['id']);
  console.log(id);
})
```